# 3d gltf model rendering optimization (threejs)

Tags: three.js, 3d, 3d-modelling, 3d-model, 3d-rendering

I have issues loading some 3d gltf models using threejs on iPad. Loading works fine actually, it loads up fine on desktop computers and android tablets, but in my specific case it needs to run on an iPad tablet and the page keeps crashing because it uses up all of the memory trying to render the model (I guess Android gives the browser more memory to use).

My question is how to optimize the model in order for it to be able to run on iPad? My first thought was that the number of vertices/indices etc. affects rendering, but it turned out that a model with more vertices and indices was able to load while the "optimized" model couldn't load. We throw the model into babylon online previewer to see its info and the thing I noticed is that the older model with more vertices and indices had less meshes and less draw calls than the new one that doesn't work. So is that something that we should focus on optimizing instead of number of vertices and indices?

The problem is that we need to optimize the model to render on iPad but I can't figure out which part of the model needs to be optimized so any help would be much appreciated!

P.S. I tried implementing DRACO compression and DRACOLoader but it doesn't help because it just compresses the file, and once it needs to be rendered on screen that compression doesn't matter at all because it's basically still the same 3d file that needs to be rendered. I can share code if needed, but I don't think it matters because there is no issues with the loading, it's just that the model is not optimized.

Comment: Are you using textures? If so, you could try reducing texture size on iPads.

Comment: @Marquizzo I tried that before your answer and that is exactly what was the problem on iPads. If you want turn this into an answer and I'll accept it. Btw. do you know how small can the texture be? We have about 15 textures and they are all just a square of one color (metalness, roughness, base color etc...), we got them from a digital agency that produced the models in 2048x2048px size and I reduced them to 512x512px. Would something like 16x16px work since the texture is just one color anyway so resolution doesn't matter maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Oversized textures were the problem. We had textures that were 2048x2048px but it was just one color inside. So I reduced all of the textures to 1x1px and it worked perfectly.